# Entire Ext JS grid needs to resize to fit contents

Tags: extjs, extjs-grid

The requirements are, the contents of the grid should never be truncated at all. The whole grid should be sized to meet the width of the data, possibly requiring a horizontal scroll bar on the window.

Is this possible?

Ext JS 4.2

Answer (score 2):

This was my final solution:

```
Ext.define('App.view.patient.MyPanel', {
    autoScroll : true,
    columnLines : true,
    extend : 'App.grid.Panel',
    width : 500,
    height : 500,
    store : 'App.store.MyPanel',

    initComponent : function() {

        // [...]

        // After store data is loaded, resize columns to fit contents
        var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup(me.store);
        store.on('load', function(store, records, options) {
            Ext.each(me.columns, function(column) {

                // Resize to contents and get new width
                column.autoSize();
                var width = column.getWidth();

                // The autoSize doesn't take config option "columnLines: true"
                // into consideration so buffer it. Bug described here:
                // http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?264068
                width = width + 3;

                // No need to go too crazy
                width = Math.min(width, 400);

                column.setWidth(width);
            });
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```